# Error "Failed to convert value of type java.util.HashMap to String" when reading from Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How to display data from firebase in text view? When the user make the appointment and click confirm then will send a notification then the notification should display my date and time from database but it has error.

[Notification Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YC7db.png)
[XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJFXU.png)

```
   myRef.child("Appointment").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           TextView mDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvdate);
           // TextView mTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvtime);
            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            Log.d("TAG",ds.child("Date").getValue(String.class));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a level in your JSON under `/Appointment` (the key starting with `n9nRQn`). Your code needs to handle this level.

One way:

```
myRef.child("Appointment").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        mDate.setText(childSnapshot.getValue(String.class));
        mTime.setText(childSnapshot.getValue(String.class));
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, please use the following code:

```
myRef.child("Appointment").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        TextView mDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvdate);
        TextView mTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvtime);

        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            mDate.setText(ds.child("Date").getValue(String.class));
            mTime.setText(ds.child("Time").getValue(String.class));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
    }
});
```

This was happening because you were missing a child in your `DatabaseReference`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use object instead which will hold your date and time.
For eg:-

```
// A new comment has been added, add it to the displayed list

        Comment comment = dataSnapshot.getValue(Comment.class);
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data

It will be simple and easy to get the data from firebase.